# Is there at least one pair from $a, b, c$ that is coprime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

I have encountered a question asked by my friend, which is stated as follows:

*Suppose there exists integers a, b, c, k, l, m such that $ka+lb+mc=1$, then, is the following statement true?*

*"There exists at least one pair from $(a, b)$, $(b,c)$,$(a,c)$ that is coprime."*

Personally, I think the statement is plausible as I can assume one of k, l, and m is zero, which would mean that there exists one pair of coprime numbers. However, I have difficulty in proving it strictly. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It is false. Example:
$$10+6-15=1$$

Comment: thank you...very clear answer